# Scanner unable to read text file

Tags: java

I have a bunch of .txt files I am trying to read but for many of them they will not read.  The ones that will not read appear to start with a blank line before the text. For example the following throws a NoSuchElementException:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("documentSets/med_doc_set/bmu409.shtml.txt"));
    System.out.println(input.next());
}
```

where the text file being read begins with a blank line and then some text.  I've also tried using input.skip("[\\s]*") to skip any leading whitespace but it throws the same error.  Is there some way to fix this?

EDIT:
The [file](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bxz3DUa2_Z2mb0xCTVZQQU5iOHc) hosted on google docs. If you download to view in a text editor you can see the empty line it starts with.

Comment: "
Abstract
Job stress can be defined as the harmful..." When I copy and paste this in the comments box it shows a blank line, then "abstract" on the next line, then the longer line.  The formatting and blank line is lost when it posts though..

Comment: with default delimiters of the scanner input, your code should print the first word from the file, even if blank lines(\n) exist at the begining. When you are calling next method, it automatically searches for the first valid token leaving the delimiters aside.

you better put the file contents here, not as a comment, but edit your question to post it.

Comment: Aside from other advice, `Scanner` hides I/O errors and you must [check for these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#ioException%28%29) explicitly. This can happen if there is an encoding error in the text file or if you attempt to read the file using the wrong encoding.

Comment: Interesting.  @McDowell I didn't know this.  I put the call to input.next() in a try block to make it throw an error and then printed out input.ioException() which gives me "java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1" which from [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/MalformedInputException.html) looks like the blank line is not a valid unicode character.  Is there a way I could just skip over it when processing the file?

Comment: @user1470948 - I've added an answer with examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Scanner` type is weirdly inconsistent when it comes to handling input. It swallows I/O exceptions - consumers should [test for these explicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#ioException%28%29) - so it is lax in informing readers of errors. But the type is strict when decoding character data - incorrectly encoded text or use of the wrong encoding will cause an `IOException` to be raised, which the type promptly swallows.

This code reads all lines in a text file with error checking:

```
  public static List<String> readAllLines(File file, Charset encoding)
      throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file, encoding.name())) {
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
      }
      if (scanner.ioException() != null) {
        throw scanner.ioException();
      }
    }
    return lines;
  }
```

This code reads the lines and converts codepoints the decoder doesn't understand to question marks:

```
  public static List<String> readAllLinesSloppy(File file, Charset encoding)
      throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, encoding);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader)) {
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        lines.add(scanner.nextLine());
      }
      if (scanner.ioException() != null) {
        throw scanner.ioException();
      }
    }
    return lines;
  }
```

Both these methods require you to provide the [encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) explicitly rather than relying on the [default encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) which is frequently not Unicode (see also the [standard constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).)

*Code is Java 7 syntax and is untested.*

Comment: Thanks so much this is what I needed.  I played around with the available charsets and found ISO-8859-1 work for the files.  I just need to construct my scanners as Scanner(new File("file/path"), "ISO-8859-1")

Answer (score 1):

It starts with a blank line, and you're only printing the first line in your code, change it to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("documentSets/med_doc_set/bmu409.shtml.txt"));
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(input.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: In my actual code I do have a while(input.hasNext()) block but the problem is that the hasNext() method evaluates to false and it never reads any of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner reads all the words or numbers up to the end of the line. At this point you need to call nextLine().  If you want to avoid getting an Exception you need to call one of the hasNextXxxx() methods to determine if that type can be read.